# Site collection user profiles not reflecting the changes made at SSP

Tags: site, sync, collection

Site collection user profiles not reflecting the changes made at SSP even after trying the commonly recommended 
stsadm -o sync -listolddatabases 0
and 
stsadm -o sync -deleteolddatabases commands.
Confirmed all the responsible jobs for profile sync are running fine. 
This is a known issue with moss 2007, and do have some fixes I believe. 
Any help on this would be of great help.

Comment: is it for one user or multiple user? what type of change to user details? what level of permission users have on site collection? make sure Database are not marked readonly / closed/offline in central admin?

Comment: Multiple users-any change like name,email- users with all kind if permissions- db status is fine in CA